# NoMethodError at /group_messages/64 undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I would like to show user's name beside group-message-comments. But I have an error message above around "<%= comment.member.name %>" on show.html.erb. How can I solve this?
I don't understand why this error happens because I put "belong_to" on group_message_comment.rb and Member model has "name" column.

☆show.html.erb(group_messages controller)

```
<p><b>Comments:</b></p>
<ul>
<% if @group_message.group_message_comments.any? %>
<% @group_message.group_message_comments.each do |comment| %>
<li>
<%= comment.content %> (by <%= comment.member.name %>)
</li>
<% end %>
<% else %>
<li>no comment yet.</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

☆member.rb

```
  has_many :friends
  has_many :messages
  has_many :comments
  has_many :group_in_members, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_in_members
  has_many :group_message_comments
  has_many :group_messages
```

☆group_message_comment.rb

```
belongs_to :member
belongs_to :group_message
```

Comment: what is the error message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happen when there is no member for perticular comment.

Add a condition here:

```
(by <%= comment.member ? comment.member.name : "Unknown" %>)
```

Comment: Mr Thaha kp, thank you very much. I made it and learned an important thing.